# TYPO3 - How can I sort a record by a field of a foreign_table and not by it's uid?

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-11.x

```
'passwordtype' => [
        'exclude' => false,
        'label' => '###label####',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide',
            'foreign_table' => 'passwordtypes',
            'foreign_sortby' => 'name',
        ],
    ],
```

That part of the tca works like a charm. The passwordtypes are getting sorted by name when I open the record of a password in the backend.

But I want the sorting of the passwordrecords also happening by the passwordtypes. So I tried 'sortby' => 'passwordtype' under 'ctrl' but that only sorts it by the uid, not by the name of the passwordtypes.

I also tried 'sortby' => 'passwordtype.name' but that creates an error. Is it possible to sort it by the name of passwordtypes instead of the uid? It clearly has the name of the passwordtypes already in the passwordlist because when I change the 'label' under 'ctrl' to 'passwordtype' than I can see the correct names and not uids.

I'm open for every idea even if I have to change my database-structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's dive into the core...

The record lists are generated via `\TYPO3\CMS\Recordlist\Controller\RecordListController::main()`. Fot getting the list itself, the method calls
`\TYPO3\CMS\Recordlist\RecordList\DatabaseRecordList::generateList()`.

`generateList()` does select data only from the actual table itself. No relations are resolved here. Then it becomes clearer why sorting by fields of a relation is not possible: they are not part of the selected data.

---

- But... The labels of foreign records are shown.

  Yes, that's done while rendering a concrete row of the list. At that
  moment, no sorting can be applied anymore.
- But... It works for sorting by UIDs.

  Yes and no. You have a 1:n relation, so the UID of the foreign record
  is saved as foreign_key in your (passwordrecords) table. The
  `'sortby' => 'passwordtype'` is not applied to the table
  `passwordtype` but to the column   `passwordrecords.passwordtype` containing these UIDs.

---

**Conclusion:**

Out of the box, there seems not to be an option for sorting by a foreign table field.

Maybe, you can hook into the recordlist by `\TYPO3\CMS\Backend\RecordList\RecordListGetTableHookInterface::getDBlistQuery()` (called in `\TYPO3\CMS\Recordlist\RecordList\DatabaseRecordList::getTable`) and modify the query parts to meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I already thought that there wouldn't be a solution but I'm still a little bit disappointed. Anyway, thanks a lot for your explanation - again!

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the order in are `foreign_table_where`:

```
   'passwordtype' => [
        'exclude' => false,
        'label' => '###label####',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide',
            'foreign_table' => 'passwordtypes',
            'foreign_table_where' => 'AND 1=1 ORDER BY name',
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: Ah sorry, my explanation probably wasn't good enough. Your answer works if I open a password-record and see the list of all my passwordtypes. But I want the list of passwords get sorted by the passwordtype names. At the moment they get sorted by the uid of the passwordtypes because I'm using "passwordtype" under "ctrl->sortby". I need something like "passwordtype.name" for example but that doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I read your post too fast. You're right, I misunderstood your question.
But then, `default_sortby` as part of `ctrl` in the passwordrecords should be working. And be careful: Do not confuse this property with `sortby` (-> see important notice in the doc): https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/Ctrl/Properties/DefaultSortby.html

Comment: Don't worry. I'm happy that someone tries to help! I added the `default_sortby="name"` in the TCA for passwordtypes and they get sorted by the name like I would use a `sortby` but I removed the `sortby`. After that I checked the sorting for my passwords and they still get sorted by the `passwordtype.uid` and not by the name. Maybe what I try to achieve doesn't work?